# IntelliJ remote Tomcat gives InstanceNotFoundException MBeanFactory

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, jmx

I'm trying to connect IntelliJ IDEA 12 to a Tomcat 6 server I have running on a remote machine, but I'm encountering an error with reason "`javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Catalina:type=MBeanFactory`".

I'm starting the Tomcat JVM with the following arguments (amongst others):

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.10.1.20"
```

I've created a "Tomcat Server > Remote" run configuration and set the JMX port to 1099 to match the above.

When I try and run that configuration, I get the following output:

```
Error running <configuration name>
Unable to connect to the 10.10.1.20:1099, reason:
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: Catalina:type=MBeanFactory
```

Does anyone know how I can avoid this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer whilst writing this question: my server.xml didn't have a ServerLifecycleListener, which - [as per the Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/listeners.html#Server_Lifecycle_Listener_-_org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener) - is required to make the MBeans available.

I added the following line to my `<Server>` element in server.xml:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
```

IntelliJ now makes the connection successfully.